# Need Sequence .css() For multi div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 divs  #BS1,#BS2,#BS3,#BS4,#BS5 ..
i need to make every one when hover on the container div ( left-section ) i need to hidden each one and delay maybe from 5000 to 2000 and back it visible again !! that`s my code

```
$("#left-section-5").hover(function () {
    $("#BS1").css("display", "none").delay(500).css("display", "block");
    $("#BS2").css("display", "none").delay(50).css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: my code not working , i trying with .animate but i think the display:none not working only top or right or bottom.... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only delays subsequent animations on the element(s) in question, and the `.css()` method is not an animation method. Use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead, which are (if you provide a duration) animation methods:

```
$("#BS1").hide(1).delay(2000).show(1);
// etc.
```

Or if you want a fancier effect try some other [effects methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), e.g.:

```
$("#BS1").fadeOut("slow").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow");
```

If by "sequence `.css()`" you mean that you want the elements to be animated one after the other you can do something like this:

```
var $divs = $('div[id^="BS"]'),
    i = 0;
function next() {
    if (i < $divs.length)
        $divs.eq(i++).animate({"opacity":0}, 300)
                     .delay(100)
                     .animate({"opacity":1}, 300, next);
}
next();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4byV/